# How to start and stop an app after receiving specific sms text?

Tags: android, gps, sms

I'm developing an android app with Android studio that should send user location via sms but I don't know how to start the app only when the app  receives a specific text.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Instructions can be found [here](https://androidexample.com/incomming-sms-broadcast-receiver) with one extra step that i outlined below in a TODO.

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                     //here you will get currentMsg body phoneNmber and senderNumber

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                   
                    //TODO launch app here!

                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }    
}
```